# PHP try catch exceptions

Tags: php, exception

Hello I have a code like that :

```
try
{
    // Here I call my external function
    do_some_work()
}
catch(Exception $e){}
```

The question is: If the do_some_work() has a problem and produce an Error this try catch will hide the error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two types of error in PHP. There are exceptions, and there are errors.

`try..catch` will handle exceptions, but it will not handle errors.

In order to catch PHP errors, you need to use the [`set_error_handler()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

One way to simplify things mught be to get `set_error_handler()` to throw an exception when you encounter an error. You'd need to tread carefully if you do this, as it has the potential to cause all kinds of trouble, but it would be a way to get `try..catch` to work with all PHP's errors.

Comment: Be aware of `set_error_handler()` can't handle **Fatal Errors** as said @hakre in his answer.

Answer (score 7):

If `do_some_work()` throws an exception, it will be catched and ignored.

The try/catch construct has no effect on standard PHP errors, only on exceptions.

Comment: You can [catch PHP Errors this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723903/php-try-catch-exceptions/7723958#7723958), but you need to enable it.

Answer (score 7):

> produce a Fatal Error

No, catch can not catch Fatal Errors. You can not even with an error handler.

If you want to catch all other errors, have a look for [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) and it's dedicated use with [`set_error_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php):

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

/* Trigger exception */
strpos();
```