# How to custom FOREIGN KEY message on Doctrine? Api platform

Tags: symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

Is this possible to display a message instead of this ?

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM plan WHERE id = ?' with params [9]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`api`.`request`, CONSTRAINT `FK_3B978F9FE899029B` FOREIGN KEY (`plan_id`) REFERENCES `plan` (`id`))
```

I would like to prevent the delete with a message "you can't delete this because its used elsewhere"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP try catch exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723903/php-try-catch-exceptions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
 * @UniqueEntity("request")
```